# can we reload the same component with different urls?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have my component "messages" and i am calling it using two different urls .when i click on first link say 'messages/1' it will load my messages inbox and i have another url 'messages/5/1' for which the component is same as for above url.when page got loaded using 'messages/1' url and when i clicked on some field which points to 'messages/5/1' .It changes the url in the header but it is not reloading the page.
i want to reload my component whenever there is different url even though they have same component .Is there any way to do this.

Comment: can you share your code? When props change react will re-render the component

Answer (score 0):

You can load the same component under different urls and it should load everything fine. Just change the path prop and add the same component you want under the component prop.

```
render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About} />
      <Route path="inbox" component={Message}>
        <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.body)
```

edit: 
You can try and use rect-router's refresh method

from https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/v0.13.3/modules/createRouter.js#L435-L437

```
 refresh: function () {
        Router.dispatch(location.getCurrentPath(), null);
      },
```

Comment: its not reloading the page .i can see that in the network tab.

Comment: react has a refresh method try using that, I've edited the answer

Comment: Where we should call this method?